# Fill Textfield from Combox

Tags: java, sql

I try to fill my Textfields from my combobox and I get the following error message and don't know why ? In the youtube videos it works

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column position '1' is out of range. The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'. at .
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnMetaData.getColumnType(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
```

```
try {
    String s = jComboBoxKunde.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sql = "Select * from ROOT.KUNDE where NAME = '?'";
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, s);
    rst = pst.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rst.next()) {
        jTFauftraggeber.setText(rst.getString(1));
        jTFtelefonnummer.setText(rst.getString(2));
        jTFemail.setText(rst.getString(3));
    }

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Is anything wrong with my `rst`?

Comment: check that if your result has data or not. if(rs.next()){}else{Sout("failed to load data");}

Comment: dont use '?' use only ? in query

Comment: i tried this then this happens : java.sql.SQLException: ExecuteQuery (String) method is not allowed in a prepared statement.

Comment: dont use             rst = pst.executeQuery(sql); use this             rst = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: my result has data the other methods like "loaddatabase" work and insert also

Comment: did you get any exception now ?

Comment: oh man it works i hate programming one little stupid thing =D thank you vermy much =)

Comment: @max58 you can [edit] your question instead of adding translation in comments next time